# apache rewrite with wordpress

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I want to redirect 
/na to the /na.php

So, I wrote like following in .htaccess. I don't want to create wordpress page for /na. Just want to redirect.

But it's not working and always show 404 error.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^na$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^na$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /na.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite from na to na.php it should be

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^na$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^na$ /na.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Regards